# Versioning Nestjs routes?

Tags: nestjs

I'm just getting started with [Nestjs](http://docs.nestjs.com/) and am wondering how I can version my API using either a route prefix or through an Express Router instance?

Ideally, I would like to make endpoints accessible via:

```
/v1
/v2
```

etc, so I can gracefully degrade endpoints. I'm not seeing where I could add the version prefix. I know it's possible to set a [global prefix](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix) on the application instance, but that's not for a particular set of endpoints.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an open discussion about the `RouterModule` https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/255. I understand how important this functionality is, so it should appear in the near future. At this point it is necessary to put `v1` / `v2` directly into the `@Controller()` decorator.

Comment: Thank you for the link! That also answers my other question on how to group routes.

Comment: great suggestion, now we have nest-route package but still I want to ask, do you feel any drawback of having version route prefix to the controller level over module level(as suggested in nest-route package)

Comment: @Kamil Myśliwiec, can you version in the following manner: `1.x`, or just `1`?

Answer (score 5):

Router Module comes to rescue, with Nest `RouterModule` it's now a painless organizing your routes.

See How it easy to setup.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '/ninja',
      module: NinjaModule,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/cats',
          module: CatsModule,
        },
        {
          path: '/dogs',
          module: DogsModule,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

@Module({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoutes(routes), // setup the routes
      CatsModule,
      DogsModule,
      NinjaModule
      ], // as usual, nothing new
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

this will produce something like this:

```
ninja
    ├── /
    ├── /katana
    ├── cats
    │   ├── /
    │   └── /ketty
    ├── dogs
        ├── /
        └── /puppy
```

and sure, for Versioning the routes you could do similar to this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '/v1',
      children: [CatsModule, DogsModule],
    },
    {
      path: '/v2',
      children: [CatsModule2, DogsModule2],
    },
  ];
```

Nice !

check it out [Nest Router](https://github.com/shekohex/nest-router)

Comment: any drawback of adding version prefix to the controller itself and include multiple controllers in single module ?

Answer (score 2):

for version or any prefix, you can use "global prefix":

https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix

Answer (score 2):

according to latest docs inside `main.ts` after `const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)` use

```
  // Versioning
  app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
    defaultVersion: '1',
    prefix: 'api/v',
  });
```

This will give all your routes a default prefix of `/api/v1` unless specified

To override version in controller use
`@Controller({version:'2'})` decorator on controller class

For overriding version at route level use `@Version('2')` above controller method

Note: If you are using swagger make sure to call `app.enableVersioning()` before `SwaggerModule.createDocument()`

Link: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning

Answer (score 1):

Best and simple way to do this is using **global prefix**

*An example is given below :*

```
import { VersioningType } from "@nestjs/common";
     
app.enableVersioning({
        type: VersioningType.URI,
      });

      app.setGlobalPrefix("api/v1"); //edit your prefix as per your requirements!
```

**You can exclude routes from the global prefix using the following construction:**

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('v1', {
  exclude: [{ path: 'health', method: RequestMethod.GET }], // replace your endpoints in the place of health!
});
```

**Alternatively, you can specify route as a string (it will apply to every request method):**

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('v1', { exclude: ['cats'] }); // replace your endpoints in the place of cats!
```